# How to use font icons in offline?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, laravel-6

I'm currently using vuetify in my laravel app and it's working fine.

The vuetify is using **material-design-icons** based on this [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#font-installation), below codes they use these two links:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now my question is how to do this in an offline way(just the font icons)? Is there an npm that we could use, and how to? Please help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install through npm using `npm install @mdi/font -D`. Check for more info [Install Material Design Icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/#installing-iconfonts)